# UItextview move up and down in iphone app( when keyboard appear and disappear)

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview

How can I move `UItextview`  up and down in a `UIScrollView` in an iphone app when keyboard appear and disappear.

Comment: You'd better do something before ask ;)

Comment: @nila code is ready for that. see my answer

Answer (score 5):

One of the way is --->in `viewDidLoad` or `ViewWillAppear` add these observer

```
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDisappeared) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
[center addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardAppeared) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

than write `keyboardDisappeared` and `keyboardAppeared` as follow

```
-(void) keyboardDisappeared
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animate" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2f];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: NO];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y+100(same as you do in keyboardAppeared), self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void) keyboardAppeared
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animate" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2f];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: NO];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y-(as much you want), self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

**UPDATE:**

**SWIFT 3.x/4.x**

Add these observer -

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

And the selector methods:

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification) {
    adjustView(show: true, notification: notification)
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification:NSNotification) {
    adjustView(show: false, notification: notification)
}

func adjustView(show:Bool, notification:NSNotification) {
    var userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardFrame:CGRect = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let animationDurarion = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! TimeInterval
    let changeInHeight = (keyboardFrame.size.height + 40/*or any value as per need*/) * (show ? 1 : -1)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDurarion, animations: { () -> Void in
        // change height Constraint or change height with changeInHeight here to your UItextView/other view
    })

}
```

**don't forget to remove observer!!!**

Comment: +1 for using notifications, but how old was the book you copied the UIView animation code from? We've had block based animation for 3 years!!!

Comment: doesn't matter @AshleyMills because code never gets old. what matter is, it doesn't affect your program efficiency.

Comment: According to Apple's docs - `beginAnimations:context:` **Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. You should use the block-based animation methods to specify your animations instead.**

Comment: Thank you @AshleyMills, I'll keep this in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Just add notification observer for keyboard's action in `-viewDidLoad` or `-viewWillAppear:`:

```
NSNotificationCenter * notificationCetner = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[notificationCetner addObserver:self
                       selector:@selector(_keyboardWasShown:)
                           name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                         object:nil];
[notificationCetner addObserver:self
                       selector:@selector(_keyboardWillHide:)
                           name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                         object:nil];
```

Then update your text view's frame in `-_keyboardWasShown:` & `-_keyboardWillHide:` methods.

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice library called `TPKeyboardAvoiding` that you can use (find it [here](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding)).

Alternatively you could program it yourself and use the `contentOffset` property of the `UIScrollView` to move the content down or upwards. You then should be listening to the `keyboardDidShow` and `keyboardWillHide` methods of the keyboard.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

First set textview's delegate and then try to implement these  methods....

```
    - (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
    {
        [self scrollViewToCenterOfScreen:textView];
        return YES;
    }

    - (void) scrollViewToCenterOfScreen:(UIView *)theView
    {
        CGFloat viewCenterY = theView.center.y;
        CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

        CGFloat availableHeight = applicationFrame.size.height - 300;            // Remove area covered by keyboard

        CGFloat y = viewCenterY - availableHeight / 2.0;

        if (y < 0)
        {
            y = 0;
        }
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, y) animated:YES];
    }

// -------- Modified --------


    - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)txtView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)tempText
{
    if( [tempText rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]].location == NSNotFound )
    {
        return YES;
    }

    [txtView resignFirstResponder];
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f) animated:TRUE];
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: You should use `UIKeyboardWillHide/ShowNotification` then you won't need to hardcode sizes.

Comment: its k but what problem in this code n y u downvote to this answer...

Comment: @Dharmbir Choudhary : I can move the textview up. but can't move down using this code

Comment: yes,I added textview in a scrollview

Comment: I tried, but it's not working. :(. It only just move down the cursor.

Comment: See now this will work perfect...Coz i've implemented it...